# Interpretation of Little's MCAR (missing completely at random) test and how to go on

Tags: mcar

My Little's MCAR (missing completely at random) test on 12 items revealed

chi-square = 138.281, DF = 84, and sig. = .000. (SPSS Output)

I wonder if I can conclude that the data were **not** missing completely at random since the p-value is highly significant (<.05)?

And, is there any issue with my p-value being p=0?

The values form a scale with 3 facets (4 items each) - is it necessary to conduct MAR (Missing At Random) or (NMAR - Not Missing At Random) given the result and what would I conclude of the additional tests?

Answer (score 3):

From Takunda's R help in the `na.test`:

> Under the null hypothesis that data are MCAR, the test statistic follows asymptotically a chi-square distribution

Therefore, with a very low $p$-value you are compelled to infer the data are MAR, or that at least one missingness pattern is predicted by one or more measured variables in the sample. This is, of course, only valid under a very contrived set of assumptions. The Enders 2010 article covers this. To add to the dilemma, the test result doesn't really give you any sound advice for how to attempt your analysis. Whether the data truly are MAR or MCAR, you stand to gain a whole lot by applying missing data methods, like mice. The only problem is that it's technically sophisticated to do these things for anything other than plain vanilla regression. But if you don't intend to handle your MAR data, then you're barking up the wrong tree by testing for it!